# Use a previously defined column in data.table column assignment

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a data.table with information on *income*, *hours worked* and the *id* of an individual.
I want to calculate the income per hour `iph` and then calculate for each individual the income development over time (`iphd`).

In the final data.table I want to store **both** variables `iph` and `iphd`.

```
data <- data.table(
  income = c(100, 120, 140, 205, 200, 220),
  hours =  c( 10,  11,  12,  18,  17,  21),
  id =     c(  1,   1,   1,   2,   2,   2)
)

(data
  [, iph := income / hours]
  [, iphd := c(NA, diff(iph)), by = id])[]
```

Being used to base R's `within` function, I would like to access iph right after its definition in the same expression. Something like:

```
# Trial no. 1
data[,
     `:=`(
       iph := income / hours,
       iphd := c(NA, diff(iph))),
     by = id][]

# Trial no. 2
data[, `:=`({
  iph = income / hours
  iphd = c(NA, diff(iph))
}), by = id][]

# Trial no. 3
data[, .({
  iph = income / hours
  iphd = c(NA, diff(iph))
}), by = id][]
```

However, none of these solutions works.
Is there a way to do this other than the two-step approach I suggested above?

Comment: Why is your first code bad? While it has the overhead of two `data.table::[` calls, it's not as if that is measured outside of the microseconds realm.

Comment: @r2evans It's just a small convenience issue. If I do this with several variables, I want to group the expression according to different variables. That is, do all steps for variable A, then do all steps for variable B, etc.. Not: Do step no. 1 for variable A and B, then (in the next "[...]") do step no. 2 vor variable A and B.

Comment: Writing it on one line does not mean data.table processes it "rowwise" and luckily not, no matter how you write it (all of the by reference) solutions do the same internally, handling column by column **by reference**

Comment: The answer by Wimpel shows that what I asked for is possible. I don't see a problem in evaluating an expression row by row even if the underlying data is processed by reference... But maybe I misunderstood your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

calculate both between `{...}` and return results in a list

```
data[, c("iph", "iphd") := {
  iph <- income / hours
  iphd <- c(NA, diff(iph))
  list(iph,iphd)
}, by = id]

#    income hours id      iph       iphd
# 1:    100    10  1 10.00000         NA
# 2:    120    11  1 10.90909  0.9090909
# 3:    140    12  1 11.66667  0.7575758
# 4:    205    18  2 11.38889         NA
# 5:    200    17  2 11.76471  0.3758170
# 6:    220    21  2 10.47619 -1.2885154
```

without curly braces:

```
data[, c("iph", "iphd") := list(income / hours, 
                                c(NA, diff(income / hours))), by = id][]
```

Comment: Hm... That looks cumbersome. It looks like no simple solution exists.

Comment: As no more answers were provided after almost a week, I assume that there is no other way to do this. Therefore, I am going to accept this answer. Thank you.